# HTML 5 multiple input file, pre loader with delete button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hi could anyone help me

got this form that will render image when I select image, I would like to have a delete button each image just in case wrong image is selected.

got no idea how to do it.

any help, comments, links, suggestion will do. Thanks in advance.

this is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/Fq6Jc/)

```
//I just copy paste the code inside my demo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the content inside #images_preview.

```
function clearContent()
{
   document.getElementById('images_preview').innerHTML="";
}
```

**Edited**

Add below code just after you render the image **(after document.getElementById('images_preview').appendChild(thumb);)**

```
var element = document.createElement("input"); 
 element.setAttribute("type", "button");
 element.setAttribute("value", "clear");
 element.addEventListener('click', clearContent, false);
 document.getElementById('images_preview').appendChild(element);
```

Comment: ya but dunno how to generate button by just selecting images, could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

In this code if you click the image a confirm box will ask you if you want to delete the image.

and removes it from DOM if you accept.

copy the addEventListener between the two lines of `//your code`

```
thumb.setAttribute('src',e.target.result);// your code

thumb.addEventListener('click',function(){
 if(confirm('delete?')){
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this)
 }
},false);

document.getElementById('images_preview').appendChild(thumb); // your code
```

if you don't need to select the image for other purposes this is prolly the fastest way.

you also interact directly with the image with (this);

to create a nice button effect i would just add css style on hover.

```
#images_preview>img:hover:after{
 //here u add a nice delete icon
}
```

if you need more buttons and the possibility to select each image i would put the image as background in a left floating div and inside the div put the different buttons you need.